# Why gvim can't work with command: p4 client?

Tags: gvim, terminal

P4EDITOR is set to gvim in .p4enviro.
When run command `p4 client` in terminal, it will pop an empty tmp file.
But if change editor config to `P4EDITOR=vim`, it works fine.
How to fix this?

Comment: Read the help at `:h -f`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, Yes, after adding `-f`, gvim works fine. Will you turn comment to answer?

Answer (score 2):

As @ChristianBrabant says:  Use gvim -f as P4EDITOR environment variable to fix this issue.

Adding the below line to .bashrc
export P4EDITOR="gvim -f"

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Normally, when users post answers from the comments that are not their own, they make it community wiki **or** add enough explanatory details to make it a high-quality answer independent of the original comment. You can use the [edit] button for this.